# Obtener valor específico de sql con php e insertarlo en una variable

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Sé que es una pregunta bastante básica, pero hasta ahora nunca había necesitado hacerlo directamente, pero cómo puedo obtener un valor específico de una tabla e insertarlo en una variable?
Ejemplo $rol=1

Por ejemplo: la tabla tiene una columna llamada "rol", cómo podría obtenerla? Leí que iterando, pero no logro entender del todo

Adjunto mi código php:

````
session_start();
require_once("conexion.php");
$ide= $_REQUEST["ide"];
$contrasena= $_REQUEST["contrasena"];

$sel= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (cedula_us='$ide') AND (contrasena='$contrasena ') ";




$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sel);

$existencia= mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar);

if($existencia ==1){
  $_SESSION['ide'] = $ide;
   echo $ide;
   
   exit();
}else{
   echo "el id no existe";
}

?> ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respecto a tu código y a tu pregunta te voy a ayudar a resolverlo e incluso intentare ayudarte a mejorar tu código, en el caso que tengas algo igual en el código que estas usando ahora:

lo primero de todo, es mejor que uses PDO, es mas seguro, y por así decirlo es como la versión mejorada de mysqli, lo segundo deberías preparar las consultas para que no fueran inyectables, por seguridad y por seguridad también, deberías de hashear las contraseñas y comparar hashes.

a continuación te dejo una muestra del código que necesitas:

```
    <?php

session_start();
require_once("conexion.php");

//ahora vamos a preparar la consulta con pdo
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE celuda_us = :ide");
//vamosa usar html_especial_chars para evitar inyecciones sql
$consulta->bindParam(':ide', htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['celuda_us']));
//ejecutamos la consulta
$consulta->execute();
//solo vamos a usar un registro
$registro = $consulta->fetch();

//ahora vamos a verificar si el usuario existe
if($registro){
    //ahora vamos a verificar si la contraseña es correcta
    if(password_verify($_REQUEST['contrasena'], $registro['contrasena'])){
        //en caso de ser la contraseña correcta vamos a tener la informacion de un solo usuario
        $_SESSION['ide'] = $ide;
        echo $ide;
        
    }else{
        //no especificamos que es lo que esta incorrecto por seguridad
        echo"Las credenciales no son correctas";
    }
}else{
    //no especificamos que es lo que esta incorrecto por seguridad
    echo"Las credenciales no son correctas";
}
```

Espero que esto te sirva y entiendas la importancia de tanto el prepare como del htmlspecilchars.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y por la información nueva que me mostraste, la tomaré en cuenta :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
// Ejecuta tu consulta SQL tal y como la tenías:
$sel = "SELECT rol FROM usuarios WHERE cedula_us='$ide' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sel);
```

Esto es lo que ya tenias hasta ahora, así que puedes hacer por ejemeplo, conseguir el valor de la columna "rol" de la primera fila de resultados asi:

```
// Obtener el valor de la columna "rol" de la primera fila de resultados:
$rol = mysqli_result($resultado, 0, 'rol');
```

Aunque esto no es muy "escalable" por que en tu consulta, en principio, tendrá varias "rows" (filas) y querrás iterar por todas ellas. Así que puedes hacer algo asi:

```
// Iterar a través de los resultados y hacer algo con la columna "rol"
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    // Haz lo que necesites con esta columna (para todas ellas)
    echo $fila['rol']
}
```

[Mas documentacion de mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp)

Espero que te sirva,

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda :)